# How to use de-morgan law in Coq to replace "not forall" by "exists"?

Tags: coq

I am learning the Coq language and trying to prove the following statement:

```
Lemma ex4: forall (X : Set) (P : X -> Prop), ~(forall x, ~ (P x)) -> (exists x, (P x)).
```

In the beginning of my proof:

```
Proof.
  intros X P A.
```

I arrive at the point where I have the assumptions

```
X : Set
P : X -> Prop
A : ~ (forall x : X, ~ P x)
```

I now want to apply de morgan law on `A` to get an assumption

```
B : exists x : X, ~ (~ P x) (*** Or something similar ***)
```

but I can't find a way to correctly use the library function. The following line

```
apply (not_all_ex_not P).
```

throws an error:

```
In environment
X : Set
P : X -> Prop
A : ~ (forall x : X, ~ P x)
The term "P" has type "X -> Prop" while it is expected to have type "Type".
```

I import the `not_all_ex_not` from using the command `Require Import Coq.Logic.Classical.`

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply not_all_ex_not in A` instead (or `apply (not_all_ex_not X (fun x => ~ P x)) in A`).

**Explanation** In Coq, you need to explicitly apply type arguments to polymorphic functions and lemmas, unless they are marked as implicit. The `not_all_x_not` lemma has only explicit arguments, and the first argument is the argument type of the predicate, which is why your attempt did not work. The `in A` is needed because your goal does not syntactically match the conclusion of `not_all_ex_not`.

Comment: Or just `apply not_all_ex_not in A.` Note that `not_all_ex_not _ P` is wrong: `A`'s type contains an additional `not` under the quantifier. It would be `not_all_ex_not _ (fun x => ~P x)` if you really wanted to say the property explicitly.

Comment: The comment of HTNW worked. The suggestion in the answer does not unify.

Comment: @mercury0114 Oops! I've updated my answer with HTNW's suggestion.